# Visual basic 2010 in textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, basic

It is posible that I whenever I input a word in textbox then click the button , the every letter when check in database if that letter has a value .. Then all results will go to textbox2?

P.S Sorry for my english

Comment: Yes it is. You're welcome.

Comment: Can you please give me some example on how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Fo example I input a word abakada in textbox1. Then that abakada has a equivalent in my database . a = ah , ba= bah , ka = ka, and da = dah.. How can I get all the equivalent of all that then go to textbox2?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different events that can occur pertaining to a text box.  A description is the key down event.  Every time backspace, arrowkey or letter is pressed, the code in this section runs.  I think this is what you're looking for.  There are other events that run when the user is no longer looking at that particular box (lose focus).  Maybe with more description we can help more.